# jquery scripts does not load upon logout of the application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

We are currently using Jquery-1.10.2.js, JQueryMobile-1.3.2.js**. We are facing the below issue only on Windows 8.

Issue: The validation scripts for username, password does not work upon logout of the application. Steps to reproduce this issue in the attached sample application **[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvq3fksfxxwk32u/WindowsPhoneTest.zip)**

```
1)enter username and password,Click login button
```

It will take you to Myaccount.html

```
2)Click logout button in Myaccount page
```

It will take you to Main page.

```
3)try to give valid username and password in main page
```

And press login button

We are not able to read values from text fields .

FYI, we have added the below lines of code before `$.ajax` in **Jquerymobile-1.3.2 js** file to have the changepage api work properly

```
 var parts = fileUrl.split("www/");
 fileUrl = "www/" + parts[parts.length - 1];
```

PS: Please do not ask to update to higher version of Jquery. Our css are designed based upon the mentioned versions, upon migrating we have to rework the css.

Comment: but did you try with newer versions of jQuery? Because if it works there, you SHOULD use it and update what needs updating. The opposite does not make sense.

Comment: there is not enough time to rework the css

Comment: Is this question resolved? What errors do you see in the output view in visual studio after entering the username and password values?